# Expected App Pool is not showing. Instead of that Generic App Pool is showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-10, application-pool

I've written code in C# to start and stop the IIS Pool. I've used **ServerManager** method and trying to user **ServerManager().ApplicationPools** but it is only showing below five application pools and not the pool I've in my IIS. My IIS version is **10.0.19041.1** . Below is the mentioned code.

IIS Pool I'm getting

"Clr4IntegratedAppPool"
"Clr4ClassicAppPool"
"Clr2IntegratedAppPool"
"Clr2ClassicAppPool"
"UnmanagedClassicAppPool"

```
 private void PerformAction(string action)
    {
       
        // Get selected server and app pools
        string selectedServer = ddlServers.SelectedValue;
        List<string> selectedAppPools = new List<string>();

        foreach (ListItem item in cblAppPools.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                selectedAppPools.Add(item.Value);
            }
        }

        // Perform start or stop action on selected app pools
        foreach (string appPool in selectedAppPools)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Trying to access App Pool: {appPool}");

                    ApplicationPool selectedAppPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools[appPool];
                    
                    if (action.Equals("start", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        selectedAppPool.Start();
                    }
                    else if (action.Equals("stop", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        selectedAppPool.Stop();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exception (log it, display it to the user, etc.)
            }
        }

        // Refresh the UI or display a message to the user
        LoadAppPools(selectedServer);
    }
}
```

Comment: That indicates your code is reading the IIS Express settings, not full IIS. You can read https://halfblood.pro/whats-microsoft-web-administration-and-the-horrible-facts-you-should-know-b82f2c974da6 to learn more.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li. I'm a newbie in c#. Can you please tell me how can achieve this. As per your suggestion I went through the posts but i didn't get any point that reflects anything about app pool. Will changing the schema only works?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as a reference:

```
// Writes out the applications and the application pool names 
// associated with the applications under the default Web site.
public void GetApplicationPoolNames()
{
   ServerManager manager = new ServerManager();
   Site defaultSite = manager.Sites["Default Web Site"];

   foreach (Application app in defaultSite.Applications)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(
        "{0} is assigned to the '{1}' application pool.", 
        app.Path, app.ApplicationPoolName);
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried using this code. What i observed here is , in the 2nd line it is showing the application name(the name of the project I'm using ) as DefaultSiteName.  To mention here. I'm using "IISExpress"  to run my code. Please suggest if i'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: What is the ApplicationPoolName you get?

Comment: I get null. Only "null" is showing and code is having the error as "object reference set to null"

Comment: I edited my code, please try again.

Comment: I tried with updated code but same null is coming as output from the 2nd line of code. This code is showing only one website name and that is "Website1". However this website is not in my IIS.

Comment: This website is the website what you want to get the application pool name.